# Bower + Rails and files in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I read a lot of articles how to integrate Rails and Bower. But what I need now basically, is little bit more complicated scenario. I have bower component with the following directory structure:

```
xx.js
xx.css
vendor
|- dir1
|---vendor-file-1.js
|---vendor-file-2.js
|- dir2
|- vendor-file.js
|- vendor-file.cab
|- vendor-file.jar
```

Basically, `xx.js` and `xx.css` is the component itself. But this component is usable only when vendor files are attached to the page with script tags. These vendor javascript files are using cab and jar files. I don't want to modify vendor files, and the path to `cab` and `jar` files is hardcoded in vendor-file.js (loaded from the same directory).

So I plan to use my component the standard bower-rails way. And I plan to attach vendor files to the page (when it's required) with script tags.

So, for this reason I need to put all of the vendor files into `./public` folder.

I can try to configure it with `.bowerrc` and `directory` parameter. But in this case I don't know what to do with other components. Is there any way to configure bower to have "directory" parameter for each bower component and not for all of them?

Or any other ideas how to deal with `cab` and `jar` file if something is loading them from the same directory?